# Replace all past values from a field with last value

Tags: sql, replace, google-bigquery

I have a specific field in BigQuery that I want to change and fill out all values from the same user with its last value from max datetime.

This is the original data:
[image: table1]

This is the wanted result:

[image: newfield]

I have already tried with Coalesce, case when, row_number() over partition by etc.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
    COALESCE (segment, LAST_VALUE(segment IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY datetime DESC)) newsegment
```

I still get the same result as in the first image since it takes the value with max characters

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `'UNACTIVE'` to `NULL`:

```
SELECT T1.*,
       LAST_VALUE(NULLIF(segment, 'UNACTIVE') IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY datetime DESC)
FROM T1;
```

Because of how `LAST_VALUE()` is defined, it does not need the `COALESCE()`.  It will pull the value from the current row if it is there.

Comment: FIRST_VALUE with DESC without conversion produce desired output?

Comment: Thank you, but I shouldn't convert the "unactive" to null, there are specific cases where a userID only has the "unactive" state. It has to remain the same if its last one is "unactive". Also, I tried your query returns but it returns null values for every "unactive" row.

Comment: @June7 FIRST_VALUE with DESC works!! Thank you!! very helpful

FIRST_VALUE((segment) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY userID
ORDER BY dateTime
 desc) as newsegment

Comment: @DanielaBaluta . . . Oh, you are putting *future* values into a row.  I changed the sort order to `DESC` to bring in future rather than past values.

Comment: @june7 I would need to apply the following as well but I'm a bit stuck: If the user had a segment different than UNACTIVE --> then retrieve the segment he had in its last visit ignoring all UNACTIVE results. If the user only had an UNACTIVE segment, then UNACTIVE

Answer (score 0):

Use FIRST_VALUE with DESC condition. Coalesce is not needed. Also, calculate FIRST_VALUE field in SELECT before FROM clause.

```
SELECT T1.*, FIRST_VALUE((segment) IGNORE NULLS) 
OVER (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY datetime DESC) AS NewSegment 
FROM T1;
```

However, I would expect LAST_VALUE to work with ascending order.

Comment: What if I want to add the following condition?

If the user had a segment different than UNACTIVE --> then retrieve the segment he had in its last visit ignoring all UNACTIVE results. If the user only had an UNACTIVE segment, then UNACTIVE.

Comment: I don't understand that. I don't see how that is a new condition. Perhaps you should edit your original question or start a new one. Provide example data.